# Control Access Module in Drupal slows down he site

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Whenever i enable content access module in drupal it slows down the site a lot , disabling it makes the site load properly. Are there any other modules which could be instead of content access?

Aditya

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking what other access modules you can use, you might try [Nodeaccess](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess)

There are many more as well, see a list of possible modules at http://drupal.org/node/270000

Answer (score 0):

Other content access modules might just was result in the same slowdown. All these modules just add access rules to Drupal, the part that actuall looks for the permission is in Drupal core.

Instead, what I would try to do is install devel.module and print the executed sql queries. Then, look queries are actually slow and try to optimize them by adding indexes.

Maybe this only happens in combination with another module because it executes crappy queries.